# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não consigo criar essa chave estrangeira.

Segue o meu código:

```
CREATE DATABASE escola2;
   USE escola2;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aluno (
    matricula INT,
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    sobrenome VARCHAR(30),
    cod_curso VARCHAR(20),
    periodo INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS professor (
    codigo INT,
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    sobrenome VARCHAR(30),
    curso_ministrado VARCHAR(30),
    setor VARCHAR(30),
    salario DECIMAL(8,2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE estado_civil(
    id_estado INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    estado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id_funcionario INT NOT NULL,
    foreign key(id_estado) references aluno(matricula)
);
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados? a resposta abaixo já ajudou ?

Comment: Pela sintaxe `ENGINE=InnoDB`, eu diria que é MySQL ou MariaDB. De qualquer forma, de fato, as tags deveriam ter especificado qual o gerenciador de banco de dados usado.

Comment: Victor Santos, ao invés de editar o título da sua pergunta para resolvido aceite a resposta do Victor Safusa (em baixo do marcador de votos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
CREATE DATABASE escola2;
USE escola2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aluno (
    matricula INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    sobrenome VARCHAR(30),
    cod_curso VARCHAR(20),
    periodo INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS professor (
    codigo INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(25),
    sobrenome VARCHAR(30),
    curso_ministrado VARCHAR(30),
    setor VARCHAR(30),
    salario DECIMAL(8,2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE estado_civil (
    id_estado INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    estado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    id_funcionario INT NOT NULL,
    foreign key(id_estado) references aluno(matricula)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

O problema me parece que era porque você não havia definido as chaves primárias de `aluno` e `professor`.

Comment: Nossa, agora que vi que inocência a minha. Muito obrigado Victor Stafusa.

Comment: @VictorSantos Se minha resposta te serviu, não se esqueça de marcá-la como correta/aceita ao clicar no ✅ verde aqui do lado. Obrigado. :)

Comment: Obrigado, sou novo no Stackoverflow nunca tinha usado !!! Marquei como correta !!!